# Fire TriggeredSends from ExactTarget's API using HttpClient REST

Tags: c#, rest, salesforce, exacttarget

I've read along the way that Salesforce (I'm extremely new to this 3rd party platform) has a `FUEL SDK` which one can use instead of the version (using `HttpClient -- REST` instead of `SOAP`).

Please correct me if using `FUEL SDK` is the only way to go about requesting Salesforce's endpoints. Currently I am attempting to hit ExactTargets's API endpoints using `HttpClient`. These are the tutorials I've been basing my code off of:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/get-access-token.htm

**Wanted Result:**

To be able to request a `Triggered Send` email based off a template inside of `ExactTarget`.

**Problem:**

**The Salesforce endpoint continuously returns a 404. I am able to receive the authorization token successfully.** The `GetAccessToken` method is omitted for brevity

https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:MyExternalKey/send

I do not understand why the 2nd `POST` request to `//www.exacttargetapis.com/.....` returns a 404 but the authorization works. This leads me to believe that I do not have to use the `FUEL SDK` to accomplish triggering a welcome email.

---

**Code:**

```
    private const string requestTokenUrl = "https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken";
    private const string messagingSendUrl = "https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends";
    private string exactTargetClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExactTargetClientId"];
    private string exactTargetClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExactTargetClientSecret"];

    private string TriggerEmail(User model, string dbName)
    {
        var etExternalKeyAppSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(dbName));
        if (etExternalKeyAppSetting != null)
        {
            string etExternalKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[etExternalKeyAppSetting];

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(string.Format(@"{0}/key:{1}/send", messagingSendUrl, etExternalKey)),
                DefaultRequestHeaders =
                {
                    Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", this.GetAccessToken())
                }
            };

            try
            {
                var postData = this.CreateExactTargetPostData(model.Email, etExternalKey);
                var response = client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress
                                                , new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData).ToString()
                                                                        , Encoding.UTF8
                                                                        , "application/json")).Result;

                // get triggered email response
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string message = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        return "testing";
    }

    private object CreateExactTargetPostData(string email, string extKey)
    {

        var fromData = new
        {
            Address = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AwsSenderEmail"],
            Name = "Test"
        };

        var subscriberAttributes = new { };

        var contactAttributes = new
        {
            SubscriberAttributes = subscriberAttributes
        };

        var toData = new
        {
            Address = email,
            //SubscriberKey = extKey,
            //ContactAttributes = contactAttributes
        };

        var postData = new
        {
            From = fromData,
            To = toData
        };

        return postData;
    }
```

---

I have also tried using `Advanced REST Client` using the following:

**URL:** 
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:MyExternalKey/send

**POST**

**Raw Headers:**

- Content-Type: application/json
- Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

**Raw Payload:**

```
{
    "From": {
        "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
        "Name": "Code@"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "example@example.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "Region": "West",
                "City": "Indianapolis",
                "State": "IN"
            }
        }
    },
    "OPTIONS": {
        "RequestType": "ASYNC"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was my App in the AppCenter was pointing to the incorrect login for MarketingCloud =(